Error saving JavaScript code in Logic App despite selecting an integration account
I have a workflow in which I want to execute some JavaScript code. For this example, I’m using the following code:

However, when I try to save the workflow, the following error appears:

I don’t understand the cause of this issue, as I have already selected an integration account in the Logic App - Workflow settings.
What am I missing?
1º Edit: Resources are on same location


Did you  set integration account correctly? and are you using Consumption or Standard Plan?

If you are using Consumption plan, make sure that both integration account and Logic app are in same Location as below:


and Now in Logic app Workflow setting:

Design:

Output:
Then Workflow is saved:

Give 5 min time and later run the trigger:

In Standard Logic app, you do not even need a integration account just use below design:

Output:


yes they are both on same location "Spain Central" I also upgraded integration account from free to standard, but it returns the same error. If it is for some utility the logic app plan is set on "Consumption".
